# batch insert for large rows to prevent log is full due to ACTIVE_TRANSACTION

Tags: sql, sql-server, logging, sql-server-2014, batch-processing

I have a table with 3+ million rows. When trying to insert them into another table I got the well known "`log is full due to ACTIVE_TRANSACTION`" error. Researching online there seems to be only three solutions:

1. change the logging type
2. increase log space
3. insert in batches

I, like many others, can't do #1 or #2 because I don't have the rights on the DB. So that leaves #3.

As we have numerous tables in our DB that will hit this condition I am writing a stored procedure that will take a source and destination table name, and a batch size, and it will do the inserts in batches.

But then I got to thinking that this seems to be a quite common problem so maybe there is some existing/built-in/standard solution I should be using instead?

Does SQL Server 2014 have a built-in mechanism to handle this situation? Or, am I making this more complicated than it has to be and there is an easier way?

Comment: What is your database recovery model?

Comment: Right now it is SIMPLE but I have no control of it. In fact, it might change in the future and I wouldn't be notified.

Comment: In SIMPLE mode you can have minimal logging if you are inserting in a table without indexes and use TABLOCK hint.

Comment: Alternatively, you can use SELECT INTO instead of insert that is also minimally logged

Comment: `SELECT INTO` only works if the table doesn't exist. The table I am inserting into already exists. And it has indexes. Not sure about TABLOCK hint but I will read on that.

Comment: >>>The table I am inserting into already exists. And it has indexes.<<< If you cannot disable indexes even con TABLOCK your INSERT will be fully logged. If you are on Enterprise Edition you can partition your table, make SELECT INTO that will create a new table, then add all the indexes and switch this table as a partition. This will be minimally logged